# jQuery: smooth the effect that works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

ok, I tried to do a script to show a hidden div but filling the full width and pushing all boxes below it down. it works but there is a delay with the boxes that are below of the box that is active you can see the example,

Can you help me to improve my code or maybe help me to find another way to get this effect?

Thank you.

Snap to be clear. (I hope so)
https://monosnap.com/file/4US3L1T16zQ74wxGD0O0IOEq1NhAxu

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.offsetRelative = function(top) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $this.offsetParent();
    var offset = $this.position();
    if (!top) return offset; // Didn't pass a 'top' element
    else if ($parent.get(0).tagName == "BODY") return offset; // Reached top of document
    else if ($(top, $parent).length) return offset; // Parent element contains the 'top' element we want the offset to be relative to
    else if ($parent[0] == $(top)[0]) return offset; // Reached the 'top' element we want the offset to be relative to
    else { // Get parent's relative offset
      var parent_offset = $parent.offsetRelative(top);
      offset.top += parent_offset.top;
      offset.left += parent_offset.left;
      return offset;
    }
  };
  $.fn.positionRelative = function(top) {
    return $(this).offsetRelative(top);
  };
}(jQuery));
$(function() {

    $('.service2-box a').click(function() {

      var k = $('.container').width();

      if ($(this).closest('.service2-box').hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).closest('.service2-box').removeClass('open');
        $(this).closest('.service2-box').find('.contentMega').slideUp(100);
        $(this).closest('.service2-box').css('padding-bottom', 0);
      } else {

        $('.service2-box').css('padding-bottom', 0);
        $('.service2-box .contentMega').hide();
        $('.service2-box').removeClass('open');

        $(this).closest('.service2-box').addClass('open');
        var position = $(this).closest('.service2-box').positionRelative('.displayimagesflex');
        $(this).closest('.service2-box').find('.contentMega').css({
          left: position.left * -1,
          top: 180,
          width: k
        });

        $(this).closest('.service2-box').find('.contentMega').slideDown(100, function() {
          var h = $(this).closest('.service2-box').find('.contentMega').outerHeight() + 15;
          $(this).closest('.service2-box').css('padding-bottom', h);
        });

      }
      return false;
    })
  })
```

```css
.displayimagesflex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
}

.service2-box .contentMega {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #a80532;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row displayimagesflex">
    <div class="col s4 box-wrapper service2-box">
      <div class="visible-cotent">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        <a class="MORE" href="#">Clic to see more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-cotent contentMega">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s4 box-wrapper service2-box">
      <div class="visible-cotent">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        <a class="MORE" href="#">Clic to see more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-cotent contentMega">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s4 box-wrapper service2-box">
      <div class="visible-cotent">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        <a class="MORE" href="#">Clic to see more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-cotent contentMega">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s4 box-wrapper service2-box">
      <div class="visible-cotent">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        <a class="MORE" href="#">Clic to see more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-cotent contentMega">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </div><div class="col s4 box-wrapper service2-box">
      <div class="visible-cotent">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        <a class="MORE" href="#">Clic to see more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-cotent contentMega">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </div><div class="col s4 box-wrapper service2-box">
      <div class="visible-cotent">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        <a class="MORE" href="#">Clic to see more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-cotent contentMega">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </div><div class="col s4 box-wrapper service2-box">
      <div class="visible-cotent">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        <a class="MORE" href="#">Clic to see more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-cotent contentMega">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </div><div class="col s4 box-wrapper service2-box">
      <div class="visible-cotent">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        <a class="MORE" href="#">Clic to see more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-cotent contentMega">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </div><div class="col s4 box-wrapper service2-box">
      <div class="visible-cotent">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        <a class="MORE" href="#">Clic to see more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-cotent contentMega">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </div><div class="col s4 box-wrapper service2-box">
      <div class="visible-cotent">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        <a class="MORE" href="#">Clic to see more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-cotent contentMega">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest using [Bootsrap Dropdowns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)

Comment: Thanks but is not like a mega menu, I need to push down the other elements, like this:

https://monosnap.com/file/4US3L1T16zQ74wxGD0O0IOEq1NhAxu